# Finding root in union find algorithm in log*n time

Tags: algorithm, tree

I know the basic method of union find using balanced tree method, and it states that there is a method to find the root of a node in a log*n method, the code for the root finding process is (copied directly from the article):

```
int root (int Arr[ ] ,int i)
{
   while(Arr[ i ] != i)
   {
       Arr[ i ] = Arr[ Arr[ i ] ] ; 
       i = Arr[ i ]; 
   }
   return i;
}
```

Here `Arr[j]` stores the parent of the node `j` and we need to find the root of node `i`, assume tree is already created. But I am not able to prove that its `log*n` time complexity. As we iterate through all the elements we check for the grand-parent, so it's `O(logn /2)` time complexity that's same as `O(log n)`, but the article states that its `O(log* n)`, what's wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the asterisk symbol supposed to mean; is it possible that this is some typographical convention?

Comment: it's the recursive logarithm of n i.e. log(log(log .... n)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoted log* time bound is an *amortized* running time for a [union-find implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) with both union-by-rank and path compression, so it only applies on average to sufficiently many operations. It can actually be improved to inverse Ackermann, which is even smaller than log*. As you observe, the *worst-case* time of each operation is Theta(log n).